# Not able to get woocommerce featured Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display 6 featured products with their thumbnails, price and title. But I am not able to see anything, however if I use `$loop->found_posts` I can see there are 6 records fetching back from database.
I have also added these lines in `wp-config.php` to see the errors but I am not able to see any error on the page

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
if (WP_DEBUG) {
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
```

**here is my code for displaying featured posts**

```
<?php
    $args = array (
                    'post_type'=>'product',
                    'meta_key'=>'_featured',
    'posts_per_page'=>6
    );
    $loop= new WP_Query($args);
    //echo $loop->found_posts;
    while($loop->have_posts()): the_post();
    echo '
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="custom-product">
        <img src="'.woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(300,335).'">
        <div class="price-title">
            <h2>'.the_title().'</h2>
            <h3>'.$product->get_price_html().'</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: You're saying, you can't see anything. Do you mean by that, that loop dosen't echo anything or you have HTML with blanks?

Comment: try adding `'meta_value' => 'yes',` in your `$args` array and do `$product = get_product( $loop->post->ID );` to get product details.

Answer (score 3):

Few suggestions here:

- You should use:

  ```
  while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  while( $loop->have_posts() ): the_post();
  ```

  because otherwise you are setting up posts related to the global `$wp_query` object.
- Note that `the_title()` doesn't return the value, it is `echo`-ing it.
- Make sure `$product` is defined in your loop.
- Use `wp_reset_postdata()` after your secondary query,  to restore the global `$post` variable.
- You can use the `posts` property of `WP_Query`:

  ```
  var_dump( $loop->posts );
  ```

  to peek into the array of queried posts.
- To check the generated SQL query, we can use the `request` property of `WP_Query`:

  ```
  echo $loop->request
  ```

  This can come handy when we need to debug our query.

Comment: `the_title()` is displaying title, for concatenating you need string. For this purpose `get_the_title()` comes in handy. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: thanks for the additional info @PaulTomkiel - yes that function is handy or we might alternatively use  `the_title( '', '', false ) ` to return the title value.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected. `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail` echoes the image tag HTML, what you need to pass as parameter is an existing thumbnail name, and width and height of the placeholder.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'meta_key' => '_featured',
        'posts_per_page' => 6
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    global $product;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="custom-product">
                <?php echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'shop_catalog', 300, 335 ); ?>
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

You can set custom image dimensions as stated here -> [WooCommerce Codex](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/set-woocommerce-image-dimensions-upon-theme-activation/)

Comment: i did similar things but it is not working. Then i tried with for same thing again. please check mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171460/how-to-fix-bootstrap-carousal-for-featured-product-in-woocommerce

Comment: The code was tested before publishing, it is fully working. Where in the theme are you testing the code?

Comment: It can display featured posts but in my case it is also displaying extra posts that don't exist. Please check my link above so you can know what i mean.

Comment: Your iteration has a complexity of O(n^2), apart from being malformed and redundant. Let's move to that post, there's nothing left here to do :)

Comment: Yes solve it after adding 'meta_value' => 'yes',  into your code. thank you very much. here is upvote for it. without that meta_value it will add unfeatured post if featured posts number are less.

Answer (score 0):

shop_catalog My first hit on google returned the following [link](http://biostall.com/how-to-display-woocommerce-featureds-product-without-a-shortcode).

Based on their instructions i updated your code.
The following code should work:

```
<?php
    $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'meta_key' => '_featured',
                    'meta_value' => 'yes', 
                    'posts_per_page' => 6
    );
    global $post;
    $loop= new WP_Query($args);
    //echo $loop->found_posts;
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
    $post = $loop->post;
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $product = get_product( $loop->post->ID );
    echo '
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="custom-product">
        <img src="' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail('shop_catalog ', 300,335) . '">
        <div class="price-title">
            <h2>' . get_the_title(). '</h2>
            <h3>' . $product->get_price_html() . '</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Try this ! Works for me

```
 <?php
 $featured_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'tax_query' => array(
             array(
                 'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                 'field'    => 'name',
                 'terms'    => 'featured',
                 'operator' => 'IN'
             ),
      ),
 ) );
 ?>
```